# Unexpected go back on react-navigation for nested navigations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I am facing a navigation issue in `react-native 0.66.4` and `react-navigation 4.4.4`.
I have a Tab Navigation setup that looks like this.

- Tab Navigation

  - Home

    - Screen A(Intial)
    - Screen B
  - Trade

    - Screen 1 (Intial)
    - Screen 2
    - Screen 3

Screen 1 Leads to 2 or 3

I am trying to navigate from Home Tab (Screen A) to Trade Tab (Screen 2 and Screen 3) using separate buttons, I am able to achieve that by doing `navigation.navigate('Trade', { screen: 'Screen2', params:{...} })` and `navigation.navigate('Trade', { screen: 'Screen3', params:{...} })`

The issue I am facing now is that

1. When I navigate to Trade (Screen2) and use the back button, it navigates to Home (ScreenA)
2. Navigating to Trade (Screen3) and then using the back button goes
   this way **Trade(Screen3) => Trade(Screen 2) => Home(ScreenA)**, and
   like this **Trade(Screen2) => Trade(Screen 3) => Home(ScreenA)** if
   I visited Screen 3 first and to achieve this I have to click back
   twice.
3. Finally, if I have visited Screen 2 or 3 before clicking on
   the Trade Tab, it shows that screen rather than Screen 1 (Initial).
   This is not the kind of behavior I am looking for.

How can I do it such that whenever I go back from either Trade (Screen 2 or Screen 3),it navigates to Trade (Screen1), and also clicking the Trade Tab after visiting either of these screens ( 2 and 3) navigates to Screen 1 (initial)?

How can I na

Answer (score 6):

When you navigate from one tab to another tab with a nested stack, you will need to pass the initial: false parameter to prevent the first page from being considered the initial.

```
navigation.navigate('TradeStack', { screen: 'Screen2', initial: false, params: { param_1: 'foo' } })
```

Then when you press goBack() on Screen2 - it will go up the stack to screen 1 (initial)

Answer (score 0):

> and also clicking the Trade Tab after visiting either of these screens
> ( 2 and 3) navigates to Screen 1 (initial)?

To achieve this I think you can use the **initialRouteName** prop as specified in the official docs(check **StackNavigatorConfig**). Please try that and let me know how it goes.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator

> How can I do it such that whenever I go back from either Trade (Screen
> 2 or Screen 3), it navigates to Trade (Screen1)

Can you do a test for these screens? Create a button and **onPress** do

```
navigation.goBack()
```

and please let me know if everything works fine. I don't have my development environment with me so I'm writing this just from reference.

Comment: 1. I have initialRouteName set as Trade already, Everything works fine when I click on the Tab menu to go Trade. I believe the issue is because I am trying to route to a deeply nested screen (Screen 2 or 3), both screens are routed to through Screen 1 by default, i.e Trade => Screen 1 => (Screen 2 or 3).

Comment: ```navigation.goBack()``` produces the same result

Comment: can you please share your router code for Trade (screens 1, 2 and 3), It would be really helpful